# OSX, code signing private keys

Tags: macos, code-signing, private-key

Where can I find the private key used to generate the mac code signing certificate?

I have looked within keychain but cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay quite simple now I have found the solution. In order to view the private keys used when signing you need to open keychain as root.

```
sudo /Applications/Utilities/Keychain\ Access.app/Contents/MacOS/Keychain\ Access
```

When opened view the login chain > Keys. Your private and public keys for your certificates will be found here. You can then right click to export these out.